# Get "client details" in Client Credentials Grant Tokens

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I'm using Laravel passport's `Client Credentials Grant Tokens` [Docs link](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/passport#client-credentials-grant-tokens), `client` middleware and MongoDB as well.

How to get client details after request passes through middleware.
Because, In Controller I'm getting `$request->user()` as `null`.

Comment: use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;   have you tried with facade
Auth::user() should return all column of user

Comment: Which middleware are using? The middleware you linked to is the CheckClientCredentials which doesn't add any details to the request.